# Correlation between dependent variable and the covariate in an ANCOVA

Tags: ancova

I want to check the effect that a categorical between-subjects factor A and a continuous predictor B has on a certain dep. variable. I created an ANCOVA with A as a factor and B as a covariate. This should tell me whether there is a main effect of A on the DV, but is this ANCOVA the correct statistical model to use in order to see if B also has an effect on the DV, in other words if A correlated with the DV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is just a regression equation, after all. You can look at the table of coefficients (or "solution", in some software) to see the estimate and $t$ test of the coefficient of $B$. This will test the contribution of $B$, after adjusting for $A$.